# what is the equivalent of as Object,.Factory, byVal in vb.net to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

What is the equivalent of as `Object`, `.Factory`, `ByVal` in VB.NET to c#?

Here's the code

```vb
Dim mobjCNLib As Object
Dim mCache As CacheObject.Factory

Public Function GetPiece(ByVal strGlobal As String, ByVal strNodes As String, 
ByVal strCode As String, ByVal intPiece As Integer)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Object` is the VB alias for `System.Object`. In C#, the alias is `object` (lowercase), and in both languages, you could also use `System.Object`.

`CacheObject.Factory` is a specific library type. It will be identical in C#.

`ByVal` has no equivalent keyword in C#. The lack of the `ref` keyword in C# implies 'by value'. (Note that it is optional in VB. If you omit it, VB assumes `ByVal`).